# Private inheritance and swap

Tags: c++, private-inheritance

I'm using private inheritance in the implementation of two very related classes.  The `using Base::X;` is very useful and elegant.  However, I can't seem to find an elegant solution for reusing the base class's swap function.

```
class A
{
public:
   iterator       begin();
   const_iterator begin() const;
   const_iterator cbegin() const;

   A clone();

   void swap( A& other );
};

class Const_A : private A
{
public:
   // I think using A::A; will be valid in C++0x
   Const_A( const A& copy) : A(copy) { }

   // very elegant, concise, meaningful
   using A::cbegin;

   // I'd love to write using A::begin;, but I only want the const overload
   // this is just forwarding to the const overload, still elegant
   const_iterator begin() const
   { return A::begin(); }

   // A little more work than just forwarding the function but still uber simple
   Const_A clone()
   { return Const_A(A::clone()); }

   // What should I do here?
   void swap( Const_A& other )
   { /* ??? */ }
};
```

So far the only thing I can come up with is copy-pasting `A::swap`'s definition into `Const_A::swap`'s definition, YUCK!

Is there an elegant solution to to reuse the private base class's swap?

Is there a cleaner way to implement what I'm trying to do here (a const wrapper for a class)?

Comment: Did you mean to return `iterator` (instead of `const_iterator`!) for `begin`? Otherwise I don’t see the sense in having two functions, and to override the function in your derived class.

Comment: `std::vector<>::begin() -> iterator` and `std::vector<>::begin() const -> const_iterator`.  This is exactly what I did and my classes have similar semantics.  Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: got it, you’re right. But what is the `cbegin` method for, then?

Comment: Why not just use `const A` in place of `Const_A`? @Konrad: AFAIK, it's for the problem where this might be "unsafe" to me: `for (auto i = cont.begin(); ...)` because of `cont` is non-const, I get a mutable iterator, even if I don't want to mutate the elements. I could cast a `const` into  the container use then use `begin`, or just use `cbegin`.

Comment: @GMan: My class has the same problem that `iterator` does for the standard containers.  `iterator == byte*`, `const iterator == byte* const` and `const_iterator == const byte*`.  I have similar semantics for my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, can’t you just call the base’s version of `swap`?

```
void swap( Const_A& other )
{
    A::swap(other); // swaps the `A` portion of `this`.
    // …
}
```

In place of `…`, you’d normally swap the members pertaining only to `Const_A`, not `A` but since there aren’t any in your particular case, this is all that you should need.

Comment: `Const_A` is not convertible to `A`.

Comment: @caspin: yes, it is: you are *inside* `Const_A`, and `Const_A` itself knows that it’s convertible to `A`, even if the rest of the world doesn’t.

Answer (score 3):

You can do as with the rest of the methods:

```
void Const_A::swap( Const_A& other ) {
   A::swap(other);
   // here any specifics
}
```